# Where can I find the book Ujjvala nilamani of Srila Rupa Gosvami?

Tags: scripture, philosophy, bhakti, gaudiya-vaishnavism

I am looking for the book Ujjvala nīlamaṇi. It is by Śrīla Rūpa Gosvāmī and has commentaries as well. Where can I find?

Answer (score 2):

The pdfs can be found at the following links:

1. https://archive.org/details/TheUjjwalaNilamaniRupaGoswamiKavyamala95/mode/2up (Includes the commentaries of Śrīla Jīva Gosvāmī and Śrīla Viśvanātha Cakravartī)
2. https://archive.org/details/UjjvalaNilamani/mode/2up (includes the commentary of Śrīla Jīva Gosvāmī and Śrīla Viśvanātha Cakravartī along with the hindi translation of Jīva Gosvāmī's)
3. http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/35661 (includes Śrīla Jīva Gosvāmī's commentary and translation of main text by Rāmanārāyaṇa Vidyāratna)
4. https://archive.org/details/20191028_20191028_2212/mode/2up (bengali translation)